# Horizontal ListView flutter WITHOUT explicit height

Tags: flutter, horizontallist

I'm trying to create a Horizontal scrolling `listview.builder()` with no pre-set height.

I've tried setting `shrinkwrap` to true and wrapping it inside an Expanded/Flexible.

The only way (that i have found) to currently achieve the desired effect is to wrap a row inside a `singlechildscrollview` inside a column, as per this answer ([Flutter: Minimum height on horizontal list view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50155738/flutter-minimum-height-on-horizontal-list-view)).

The problem with that method is that there is no builder method to load dynamic data into the Cards inside the `singlechildscrollview`.

My question is how do i create a Horizontal `listview` that that generates the output by the `row` nested inside the `singlechildscrollview` ([Flutter: Minimum height on horizontal list view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50155738/flutter-minimum-height-on-horizontal-list-view)) but with a builder method?

**With Flexible**

```
Scaffold(
  body: Container(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        Flexible(
          child: ListView.builder(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            itemCount: 3,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return FeaturedCard();
            },
          ),
        ),
        Flexible(
          child: ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: 10,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return FeaturedCard();
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
)
```

**Result**: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKiWo.jpg

**With nested `row` inside `singlechildscrollview`** (The method that works)

```
 Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16, bottom: 8),
  child: Column(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    children: <Widget>[
      SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            FeaturedCard(),
            FeaturedCard(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
)
```

**Result:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/va3TY.jpg

Notice the added space inside the card when using flexible (this actually renders worse on different devices)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

*Posting answer for OP who edited their answer into their question*

Solved the problem by creating a custom builder method like so:

```dart
Widget _buildFeaturedCards(List<Product> product) {
  final cards = <Widget>[];
  Widget FeautredCards;

  if (product.length > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < product.length; i++) {
      cards.add(FeaturedCard(product[i]));
      print(product.length);
    }
    FeautredCards = Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16, bottom: 8),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            child: Row(children: cards),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  } else {
    FeautredCards = Container();
  }
  return FeautredCards;
}
```

This creates the necessary scrolling widgets upfront instead of lazily like `ListView.builder` would.

Comment: The expression doesn't evaluate to a function, so it can't be invoked.

Comment: @JohnJoe Not sure what you mean by "expression". You'll have to be a lot more specific. You're also messaging the wrong person. This is the *OP's* solution.

Comment: @JohnJoe `FeaturedCard` is not defined within this scope. What did you expect?

Comment: cards is List `widget`, but `FeaturedCard` is object. Are you sure the code can work?
Error : The argument type 'FeaturedCard' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget'

Comment: @JohnJoe Why do you think `FeaturedCard` is not a `Widget`? Everything in the OP's code would say it is.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore Thank you for posting this! @JohnJoe `FeaturedCard` is a `Widget` the confusion could be as a result of the non-camel case naming sorry about that!

Answer (score 16):

The Flutter framework can only know the height of a widget once it's been built.

If you're building `ListView` children dynamically, it can't calculate the required height of the `ListView` until all it's children have been built, which might never happen (infinite `ListView`).

You can either give the `ListView` a fixed height and build its children dynamically or have the `ListView's` height depend on it's children, in which case you'd need to build all it's children upfront.

Comment: What does build a children upfront means?

Comment: @TSR It means the children cannot be built lazily(on demand). Basically, you can't use `ListView.builder`. The OP posted a solution in their question, which I have edited out and posted in a community wiki. They use a `SingleChildScrollView` with a `Row` as an alternative.

Comment: This, imo, is huge limitation of flutter