# Items in ListView get it's height

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to create a horizontal list view with some card.
I want the list view to have height X and the cards to have height Y, I don't know why but the cards are getting the height of the list view.
This is what I have:

```
class FinanceApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          color: Color(0x180000),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Header(),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(32.0),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(32.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        height: 250,
                        child: ListView(
                          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            CustomCard(),
                            CustomCard(),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

EDIT: The only thing that kinda works for me, Is to wrap the card container in another container, use padding to get the size I want, but it does not seem like a great solution.

Comment: Same question with no perfect answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50155738/flutter-minimum-height-on-horizontal-list-view

Comment: I think I saw that thread when I looked for an answer, tried what was there but still nothing. Thanks, that's so weird that there is no answer to that yet.

Comment: filed an issue at flutter repo https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/56028 we might need help from the flutter team.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this out:

```
      import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


      class StackOverFlow extends StatefulWidget {
        @override
        _StackOverFlowState createState() => _StackOverFlowState();
      }

      class _StackOverFlowState extends State<StackOverFlow> {
        @override
        Widget build(BuildContext context) {
          return Scaffold(
            body:

            Center(
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.blue,
                height: 200.0,
                width: double.infinity,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                  itemCount: 100,
                  itemBuilder: _buildItem,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        }

        Widget _buildItem (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Center(
            child: Card(
              child: Text(index.toString()),
            ),
          );
        }
      }
```

[image]

And for giving children same size consider wrapping the cards with a Container:

```
        Widget _buildItem (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Center(
            child: Container(
              height: 100.0,
              width: 100.0,
              child: Card(
                child: Center(child: Text(index.toString())),
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. What causing the items to be this size? I don't see anything here setting size to the items

Comment: @JohnDoah if we remove the `Center` widget in this code the cards are becoming full height.

Comment: yea well. don't you want them to be centered? Then use `Align(alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,)`

Comment: Great answer. Works for now. If you know the height of all the children is the same.

Comment: Thank you both! I do want the cards centered so that's okay. Still weird that we have to do this 'workaround' to achieve something that I guess should be built in.

Comment: @PhaniRithvij Well actually you can give them all the same height by wraping the card in a `Container(height: 100.0,width: 100.0,child: Card()),`.

Comment: @JohnDoah For me, thats what makes flutter awesome :D

Comment: @Taba I'm just starting with Flutter, but indeed, so far, it is pretty cool :D

Comment: @JohnDoah Have fun coding thou.